# string = textView.text, yet string is (nul)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, uitextview, writetofile

I've literally tried everything. I'm sure my mistake is going to be something as stupid and small as a missed **self**.string, but I can't seem to get it working. What my mini program does is checks if a file named Code.txt already exists. If it *does* exist, then it will load the file in a UITextView (and it does this just fine). If it *doesn't* exist, it will create a file name Code.txt. All of this works just fine.

However, when I try to save the current text inside the UITextView to the file, I am unable to save it to the string first. This is what I am trying to achieve:

Upon exiting the app: `textView.text --> codeString --> Code.txt [saved]`

Except, again, I am unable to save the textView.text to the string (`codeString`). The NSLog is returning it as a nut (see `NSLog(@"String: %@", self.codeString);` in the saveFile method).

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "BuildViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *codeString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) BuildViewController *buildViewController;

- (void)saveFile;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize textView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    textView.delegate = self;

    // Check if Code.txt exists
    NSString* documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *codeFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Code.txt", documentsDir];
    BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:codeFile];

    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");

    if (fileExists == true) {
        // Code.txt does exist, continue to viewDidLoad
        NSLog(@"Code.txt does exist");
    }

    else if (fileExists == false) {
        // Code.txt does not exist, create the file
        NSLog(@"Code.txt does not exist");
        ViewController *viewController = [ViewController alloc];
        [viewController createFile];
    }

    self.textView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // Load Code.txt
    NSString* documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* codeFile = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Code.txt"];
    NSString *codeString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:codeFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    textView.text = codeString;
    NSLog(@"Loaded Code.txt");
}

- (void)saveFile {
    // Save text to Code.txt
    self.codeString = textView.text;
    NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *codeFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Code.txt", documentsDir];
    [self.codeString writeToFile:codeFile
                 atomically:NO
                   encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                      error:nil];
    NSLog(@"String: %@", self.codeString);
    NSLog(@"Saved text to Code.txt");
}

- (void)createFile {
    NSString *documentsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *codeFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Code.txt", documentsDir];
    NSString *codeString = @"print(\"Hello, world\")";
    [codeString writeToFile:codeFile
              atomically:NO
                encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy
                   error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Created Code.txt");
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Where is saveFile called?

Comment: @JörnBuitink I apologize, saveFile is being called from the AppDelegate's applicationDidEnterBackground and applicationWillTerminate: `ViewController *viewController = [ViewController alloc];
    [viewController saveFile];`

Comment: Are you actually creating a new instance of the view controller in `applicationDidEnterBackground`?

Comment: @MattSwift in this case, the textview won't be there anymore, you call your function too late.
Try ViewControllers viewWillDisappear for example to call your function.

Comment: @JörnBuitink @Avi It seems that when I add it to the `viewWillDisappear`, it does work. However, only when I'm about to terminate the app, not when I put it in the background.

Comment: Why are you using only alloc instead of alloc + init ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is you create a new instance of `ViewController` like @Avi said.

You should get the existing instance in memory

If you want to save file when in background,you may register notification

In `viewDidLoad`,add this line

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
```

Then add this function to `ViewController`

```
-(void)enterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification{
    [self saveFile];
}
```

Then in dealloc

```
-(void)dealloc{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

Comment: My application crashes now: `[UINavigationController saveFile]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15c815600
2015-12-08 03:03:21.879 App[3485:917222] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController saveFile]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15c815600'`

Comment: Try the update way,you can register notification when enter background.